# Unable to pass a command line parameter to a conditional custom action

Tags: wix

I have a custom action that launches my installed application.  My software automatically updates through a Windows Service meaning it must run silent.  I call burn with the /q command line param and my app installs nicely.  The problem is that my application is launched when it should not be as the service is not set to interact with the desktop.  So I have followed many posts on the net that show adding a property. The problem is that the custom action still executes.  Here's what I have in my bundle:

```
<Variable Name="ISSILENT" Value="0" bal:Overridable="yes" />
<Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="foobar" SourceFile=".\bin\$(var.Platform)\foobarInstaller.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes">
      <MsiProperty Name="ISSILENT" Value="[ISSILENT]" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

Here's what I have in my msi:

```
    <Property Id="ISSILENT"/>

    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
              Directory="INSTALLDIR"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]foobarui.exe&quot;"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="asyncNoWait"
              Impersonate="yes"
             >
          ISSILENT=0
    </CustomAction>
```

Finally from the command line I specify:

```
foobar.exe /q ISSILENT=1
```

So the result should be the application is not launched but it is launched still.

Of course a much better solution would involve interrogating the WIX engine to see if the installer is running in silent mode however my understanding is that burn hides the necessary information from the installer making it impossible to tell if it's running silent.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong XML block to specify my condition.  It worked once I moved it here:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>      
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="StartServices" >
    (ISSILENT=0)
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```